# Error : Can' t connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Tags: excel, spring, jakarta-ee, window, weblogic

I've got 2 applications that are working well except on production environment for 1 feature. This feature is an excel generation from a simple table. On all my others environment the generation of the excel is OK, but when I am trying to use it on production environment. I've got this error in log and a naugthy **error 500** on my app !

> 2014-04-29 09:27:05,690 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue:
>   'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR com.btoc.reporting
>   .web.misc.MiscServletFilter - Error processing request
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.InternalError: Can' t
>   connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of
>   the DISPLAY variable.
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:949)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:523)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
>           at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
>           at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
>           at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
>           at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
>           at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>           at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:65)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>   147)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>   )
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   ava:113)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   ationFilter.java:139)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   eRequestFilter.java:54)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   ProcessingFilter.java:182)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   va:87)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)

Any leads that I can follow ? I've already compared all my java version. Like I am using a weblogic server, all my java versions are the same.

I am using (for the excel generation) the API from **apache**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a couple of options to try:

- Specify the `-Djava.awt.headless=true` parameter at startup time (either for your app or the server itself in the JVM_ARGS of the `Server Start` tab or startWebLogic.sh).
- Try `export DISPLAY=:0` before starting your weblogic server.
- Check to see if the X Server is running in another port
- Try to completely unset the display before starting the server `unset DISPLAY`

Comment: export DISPLAY=:0 didn't worked but the -Djava.awt.headless=true in the parameter worked well !
Thank you

Comment: Nice answer. Would be better if you provided some coding hints for "Check to see if the X Server is running in another port". :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is execute this command :

```
unset DISPLAY
```

And to restart your application.