# java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0'

Tags: java, linux

Environment : Linux

Project : Java

In my project I am using reports. I am transfering the generated report from one linux server to another.

For that, I did the below settings

1. Login to 192.168.12.24 and go to /home/proj1/.ssh
2. Run ‘ssh-keygen -t rsa’and press enter twice. It will generate
   id_rsa and id_rsa.pub
3. Cat id_rsa.pub and copy its contents
4. Now login to 192.168.12.23 and go to .home/proj1/.ssh
5. Run ‘cat >>authorized_keys’ and paste the content you copied in step 3
6. Run ‘chmod 600 authorized_keys’
7. Go to /home/proj1/ and run ‘chmod 700 .ssh’
8. Now from 192.168.12.24 try running ‘ssh 192.168.12.23’. you should
   be able to go into 192.168.12.23 without username and password
9. Repeat the above steps by swapping the servers

The above steps are working fine.

But, when I try to generate the report, I am getting the below exception

```
java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

I already set the

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

in bash_profile.

Comment: What's the bash_profile got to do with it? Pass the option to the java executable on the command line.

Comment: Thanks Barry, Can you explain the steps.

Comment: You should start your java program with "java -Djava.awt.headless=true <classname>"

Comment: It is a .ear project

Comment: Then you will need to find out how to pass the headless argument to the JVM for your application server. For example, in Tomcat you would set the CATALINA_OPTS environment variable. Check the documentation for setting JVM runtime properties.

Comment: I already set this configuration in bash_profile.    -Djava.awt.headless=true

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error : Can' t connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358664/error-can-t-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value)

Comment: Thanks Vzamanillo, Can you explain where i need to correct?